# update the UI from a separate thread in wp8 app

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, windows-phone-8

I am creating a small WP8 app which updates receives data from Windows Azure Mobile Service and show it to user.

Now I have a separate thread whose work is to interact with the azure service get the data and update the UI with the data while the main UI thread is doing other stuff.

I tried the following ways but failed...

1. Created a separate thread but this thread cannot update the UI as it cannot access the controls
2. Created a `BackgroundWorker` thread, but when I call the Azure Mobile Service await methods the worker thread calls its completed event and then when I call the `ProgressChanged` event it fails with exception : operation has already been completed

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 5):

You can update the UI from a separate thread by using the `BeginInvoke` method of the dispatcher:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    //Update the UI controls here
});
```

To be precise, it won't actually update the UI from the separate thread, but it will queue the action so the main thread can execute it when it's available.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `async` methods provided by Azure mobile services, you can just use an `async` method yourself. No worker thread or background thread is required.

```
private async Task UpdateUI()
{
  var result = await MyAzureMobileServiceCall();
  MyUIElement.DataContext = result;
}
```